# Kotlin indexed while and lambda notation

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

I have a JDBC resultset (call it rs) that I want to traverse, keeping track of which iteration I currently am at. For simplicity let's say we just want to print each index on a line as in the following snippet:

```
var i = 0
while ( rs.next() ) { println(i++) }
```

My goal is to avoid the use of a variable, and stick to a more functional style.

As a JDBC resultset is not an iterator, I can not simply use `rs.withIndex { println(it) }`.

I have implemented the following `iwhile` function, which pretty much does what I want:

```
tailrec fun iwhile(cond: () -> Boolean, i: Int = 0, f : (Int) -> Unit): Unit {
  if (cond ()) { f(i); iwhile(cond, i + 1, f) }
}
```

My only concern is how to call this function: I have to write either of

```
iwhile({ rs.next() }) { println(it) }

iwhile({ rs.next() }) { i -> println(i) }
```

while I would ideally want to write instead:

```
iwhile ( rs.next() ) { println(i) }
```

Note the absence of braces around the predicate, and the default name `i` instead of `it`

I know these are noob's questions, but is there a way to write iwhile so that I can use the last syntax? Why can I write `while ( rs.next() ) { println("hello") }` and not `iwhile ( rs.next() ) { println("hello") }`?

Comment: Did you know Apache created a ResultSetIterator class for that purpose? Available for download on their website ( https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/ ), doc can be found here ( http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/ResultSetIterator.html )

Comment: That's a very interesting point, and actually the one I'm planning to use. Thank you very much for its mention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own extension function to provide this functionality. I wrote this one quickly, so it might not do everything you want in terms of error handling or logging, but should be close.

```
fun ResultSet.nextWithIndex(fn: (idx: Int, next: ResultSet) -> Unit): Unit {
    var index = 0
    while(this.next()) {
        fn(index, this)
        index += 1
    }
}
```

And to call it:

```
val rs: ResultSet = getResultSet()
rs.nextWithIndex { idx, row ->
    row.getString("this_is_a_test")
}
```

What happens is, your extension function (`nextWithIndex`) takes care of looping through the `ResultSet` (this is the `while` loop) and calls the function you provide. Because your function is the last (and only) argument (`fn`) to the `nextWithIndex`, you can make this look like I think you wanted originally when you call it.

Comment: I like the idea of using extension function here. However I'm still interested in some generic indexed version of the while construct (or an explanation of why this is not possible) :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I write while ( rs.next() ) { println("hello") } and not iwhile ( rs.next() ) { println("hello") }?

Because Kotlin doesn't care about allowing you to achieve that. Scala does and there you could get that syntax.